# Matlab, save .EMF picture with strange output

Tags: matlab, plot, save

I am trying to save an EMF in Matlab and sometimes it decides to shift and overlap things. For example I see [image: What I see] but I get [image: is not what I get].

Any suggestions? I know it has something to do with the painter algorithm, but avoiding it makes the image look very poor.

Answer (score 0):

For complex figures Matlab's save is not very good. I recommend you have a look to [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) in FEX. It is the most downloaded submission for some reason!

You have a very nice explication og how/what/why `export_fig` is there in [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/export_fig#more-5470), whos author has taken over the maintenance of the package.